# Can we get all values from slickgrid?

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

i want to get all values from slickgrid, is that possible?

so not just the updated rows, but all of the records to be sent when we clicked the save changes button.

maybe anyone ever try it? o.O

Answer (score 0):

It's the same data you put in when you instantiated SlickGrid.  The original data array will be modified.